# Proving the convergence of $Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}f(U_i),n\geqslant 1$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $U_1,U_2...$ be a sequence of random variables independent and identically distributed following a uniform distribution in $[0,1]$. Let $f$ be a measurable function in $[0,1]$, such that $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx<\infty$ and consider $Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}f(U_i),n\geqslant 1$.
>   Determine if the sequence $Y_n$ converges in probability and if it converges determine the limit.

I thought of using the weak law of large numbers which states:

If $X_1,X_2...$ are independent random variables in L_2, defined on a probability space $(\Omega\mathscr{A},P)$. Then $\frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{n}\to 0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.

However I cannot aplly the theorem since it is only stated on the problem that $f$ is Riemann integrable.
I have been looking at other theorems and propositions but all of them require the variance to be finite.

**Question:**

How should I solve this question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(U_i)$ is also i.i.d. So this is immediate from SSLN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What does SSLN stand for?

Comment: Strong law of large numbers

Comment: Strong law large numbers requires $f\in L_2$

Comment: No. It requires only finite mean and this is satisfied here.

Comment: The proof I have for the Strong Law of Large Numbers requires the Kolmogorov inequality $P(\max_{1<j\leqslant n}|S_j-E(S_j)|>\epsilon)\leqslant \frac{Var(Sn)}{{\epsilon}^2}$

Comment: Therefore I need the second moment.

Comment: That is strange. Almost any book on probability theory proves SLLN with only first moment assumption.

Comment: That is strange. Almost any book on probability theory proves SLLN with only first moment assumption.

Comment: @PedroGomes I'm guessing you mean strong law of large numbers for independent variables. For i. i. d. variables we can just assume that the expectation is finite.

Comment: @PedroGomes SLLN is a very basic theorem in probability theory and this question gives you an opportunity to learn its proof without the assumption that variances are finite. Besides, it is very unlikely that you one can give an answer to this question which is simpler than the proof of SLLN in its general form.